# PHP redirect and rename file download

Tags: php, redirect, readfile

I've got the following situation: I have some files with hashed filename on a cdn. Now I want a php script which redirects to the files (download) and give them another name. Is there a way without using readfile? The problem with readfile is that it doesn't make sense to download the file from cdn to my webserver and then download the file from the webserver to local computer.

Comment: Have you tried creating a script on the CDN that accepts the request from users of your webserver and then serves the file using a filename you suggest? Essentially using readfile to load/serve the file as a different filename without it being essentially copied to the webserver (which you are right defeats the objective of the CDN in the first place).

Comment: I don't think the cdn accepts running php script on their system

Comment: Then the only alternative I could think would be to fudge it a little and rely on `MOD_REWRITE` on the CDN (if they allow that). But that would allow the file to be permanently available on that URL (which is good practice), but I suspect that you're trying to avoid exactly that.

Comment: You are right, the files are protected with a security token and so by every request the url changes...